how saturated fat increase lipoprotein number?
What is the physiological mechanism by which consuming high levels of saturated fat (but not unsaturated fats) causes higher lipoprotein numbers as measured by ApoB test?
The answer expected to refer in some way to the difference in metabolizing saturated vs unsaturated fats.

Welcome John. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [ask] section of our [help] centre. You should then [edit] to add your own researches into the topic, where you got stuck, else risk closure.

Hi, John. What @JiminyCricket. said is correct. This site requires questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research, at least a minimal effort at finding the answer yourself. Just link us to what you found and what it doesn't answer for you, or if you found nothing, what you searched for and where.
